# How to copy ONLY the elements of a list in python

Tags: python, list

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

This is what I have tried so far

```
list2 = list1.copy()`

print(list2)
```

Result [Actual] (This is what I don't want)

`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

How to get this result?
[Expected]

`1, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: smells like XY problem...

Comment: I'm guessing you want to print the elements separated by commas? 
You can achieve that with `", ".join(list1)`

Answer (score 0):

As **francoisr** commented, you can use: `", ".join(list1)`

If your original list contains stringed numbers, you can do this :

**Input 1 (List of Strings)**

```
str_num_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
print(", ".join(str_num_list))
```

**Output 1**

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

If your original list contains integer numbers, you'll have to convert each element to a string first:

**Input 2 (List of Integers)**

```
int_num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(", ".join(str(n) for n in int_num_list))
```

**Output 2**

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

*Note: In both cases, your output will be a string.*